# Why is my code showing up these errors?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

The Error is:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\User\Downloads\BLUETOOTH_CAR\BLUETOOTH_CAR.ino:1:21: fatal error: AFMotor.h: No such file or directory

 #include <AFMotor.h>

                     ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

My code is:

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor right_motor(1, MOTOR12_8KHZ);
AF_DCMotor left_motor(2, MOTOR12_8KHZ);

String readString;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  right_motor.setSpeed(250);
  left_motor.setSpeed(250);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
    delay(50);
    char c=Serial.read();
    readString+=c;
  }
  if(readString.length()>0){
    Serial.println(readString);
    if (readString =="FORWARD"){
      right_motor.run (FORWARD);
      left_motor.run (FORWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="BACKWARD"){
      right_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      left_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="LEFT"){
      right_motor.run (FORWARD);
      left_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="RIGHT"){
      right_motor.run (BACKWARD);
      left_motor.run (FORWARD);
      delay(500);
    }
    if (readString =="STOP"){
      right_motor.run (RELEASE);
      left_motor.run (RELEASE);
      delay(500);
    }

    readString="";
  }
}
```

Comment: The compiler can't find the header. If the header is in the same directory as the source, try using `#include "AFMotor.h"` instead.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the compiler can't locate the header file. Make sure you either move the library with header file to the default Arduino libraries folder or move the library to the same directory as your Arduino code and then try:

```
#include "AFMotor.h"
```